# Way of invoking setter methods using reflection based on getters of another Object

Tags: java, reflection, getter-setter

I have 2 objects which are related

One of them is of class `Attribute`, the other one is something like controller of that called `AddAttributeActionHandler`

The `Attribute` object has a lot of fields in it which I need to set in `AddAttributeActionHandler` Both classes have getters and setters some of them  are equal.

Basically what I what is to copy every available getter from the class `Attribute` and invoke according setter method on the class `AddAttributeActionHandler`

In other words I can execute the following (you can call it "manual" setting)

```
Attribute attributeObj = getAttributeObj();

String codeFromAttrObj = attributeObj.getCode();
String titleFromAttrObj = attributeObj.getTitle();


AddAttributeAction action = AddAttributeAction.create();

action.setCode(codeFromAttrObj);
action.setTitle(titleFromAttrObj);
```

The problem is that there are just like 50+ fields. I'd like it to be fully automatic.

So, I've found the following code for getting every available public getter for the object `Attribute`

```
for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : Introspector.getBeanInfo(attributeObj.getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors())
    {
        if(propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod().toString() != "null") 
        {
            String getterMethodName = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod().toString();
            String getterMethodValue = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod().invoke(attributeObj).toString());
        }      
    }
```

The code above gets every getter available in the object and prints its value.

Now I need to find out whether there's a corresponding setter method in the object of the class `AddAttributeActionHandler` and set the property which I got from the getter in the `Attribute` object.

Is it possible?

If so, please provide any clues.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use [BeanUtils.copyProperties()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.4/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) from the [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) library.

Comment: Don't use `toString()`. Use `getName()`  and `getParameterTypes()`. Then look at [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) and find out yourself...